# How to sort by Columns in Matrix in Power BI without using measure

Tags: sorting, powerbi

How can I sort by columns in Matrix in Power BI.

Let me explain a bit. I have this table (sample).

[image]

There is Unit and Rating (New Units will be always added often).

I try to show the data in Matrix in Power BI and I got this but I can't sort by High, Medium or Low at all.

[image]

I want to sort in this order (High Desc, Medium Desc and Low Dec) order.

[image]

How can I achieve it? I am quite new to Power BI.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to create an order column and use that sort on with the [Sort by Column feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-sort-by-column#sort-using-the-sort-by-column-button).

The problem though is if you write a calculated column like this:

```
Order = SWITCH(Table1[Rate], "High", 1, "Medium", 2, "Low", 3)
```

and then try to sort on that, then you'll get a circular dependency error basically saying you can't sort by a column that is dependent on the column you are trying to sort.

There are a couple of workarounds.

---

One possibility is to create your order column in the query editor, which should be a simple custom column:

```
if [Rate] = "High" then 1
else if [Rate] = "Medium" then 2
else if [Rate] = "Low" then 3
else 0
```

Use this column to sort by.

---

Another possibility is to define a new table that with your ordering preference.

Enter Data:

```
Rate    Order
-------------
High    1
Low     3
Medium  2
```

Call this table `Sort` and create a relationship with the original table on the `Rate` column.

Now create a calculated column on the original table that pulls over the `Order` value.

```
Order = RELATED(Sort[Order])
```

Use this column to sort by.

Comment: it only sort from "High", "Low", "Medium" to "High","Medium", "Low". I want to sort the order of Unit by the descending High, descending Medium and decending Low too.

Comment: Click the ... on the visual and choose Sort by Count of Rate.

Comment: It sort by the Count of Rate but it is still not right for me. If Unit A has 10 Low Rating and Unit B has 1 High Rating. Unit A is shown above Unit B. I still want to show Unit B first since the rating is High although the count is just 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use RANKX function and then use it to sort by it.

```
Sort =
var a = SELECTEDVALUE(DimTable[Rate])
Return
RANKX(
All(Table[Program]),
COALESCE(CALCULATE([Measure],Table[Rate] = a),0),
,ASC,Dense)
```

This article describes in more detail:

https://alintelligence.tech/sort-matrix-by-selected-columns-with-rankx/